# Proof for the formula of arc length of parametric equations

Tags: calculus

For the derivation of the arc length formula for parametric equations, we get the following formula:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{[f'(t^*)]^2 + [g'(t^{**})]^2} \Delta t $$
where $t^*_i$ and $t^{**}_i$ are found by using the mean value theorem on $x = f(t)$ and $y = g(t)$ respectively. $t^*_i$ and $t^{**}_i$ are values for t where the slope for the tangent line is equal to the slope of the secant line. The secant line is from $t_{i-1}$ to $t_i$.

My question is how can we take $t^*_i$ = $t^{**}_i$? Depending on the curves when using the mean value theorem on the curves $x = f(t)$ and $y = g(t)$, $t^*_i$ and $t^{**}_i$ can be equal. Generally the are not equal so how can we take them as equal and derive the following formula for arc length. The only time the limit formula above can be equal to the integration below is when $t^*_i$ = $t^{**}_i$ all the time. [This is what the book says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbMCu.jpg)

$$\int^\beta_\alpha \sqrt{[f'(t)]^2 + [g'(t)]^2} dt $$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! I suggest you to use mathjax to make your post more readable: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: As an exercise in mathjax I suggest you can implement formulas from your book to make it more understandable for other user what $t^*$ and $t^{**}$ stand for .

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Please edit your question to make clearer what you're asking. My guess is it's one of the following: (1) Why in general is $t^\ast$ different from $t^{\ast\ast}$? (2) How can we sometimes prove they're equal? (3) Given they're in general unequal, how is the arc length's integral representation proven?

Comment: The book says it can be shown for the limit, but it does not show, so it is easy to see.

Comment: @J.G. Is it better now? My question is "Given they're in general unequal, how is the arc length's integral representation proven?"

Comment: @NikPronko Is it better now?

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. You need something similar to [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_second_part) of another result. As $\Delta t\to0$, by the squeeze theorem $t^\ast\to t$ and $t^{\ast\ast}\to t$, and continuity takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

We must assume $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous (and therefore uniformly continuous) on $[\alpha,\beta]$.  We use $t_{i-1} \le t^* \le t_i$ and similarly for $t^{**}$ to find that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{[f'(t^*)]^2 + [g'(t^{**})]^2} \;\Delta t
$$
converges to
$$
\int_\alpha^\beta \sqrt{[f'(t)]^2+[g'(t)]^2}\;dt
$$
You are right, this is non-trivial.  The proof is similar to the proof that continuous functions are Riemann integrable.

---

The textbook

*Spivak, Michael*, Calculus, Houston, TX: Publish or Perish (ISBN 978-0-914098-91-1/hbk). xiv, 680 p. (2008). [ZBL1272.26002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1272.26002).

has an exercise where the reader shows that this works: Problem 2, page 263 [in the 4th edition].  The hint says: use the fact that the square-root function is uniformly continuous on a closed interval $[0,M]$.   Then Problem 3 is to prove this arc-length formula,
assuming $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous.